# Baal~Peor worship at Shittim

Tags: numbers, moses

Numbers 25:1-9 (KJV)

> And Israel abode in Shittim, and the people began to commit whoredom with the daughters of Moab. And they called the people unto the sacrifices of their gods: and the people did eat, and bowed down to their gods. And Israel joined himself unto Baalpeor: and the anger of the LORD was kindled against Israel. And the LORD said unto Moses, Take all the heads of the people, and hang them up before the LORD against the sun, that the fierce anger of the LORD may be turned away from Israel. And Moses said unto the judges of Israel, Slay ye every one his men that were joined unto Baalpeor. And, behold, one of the children of Israel came and brought unto his brethren a Midianitish woman in the sight of Moses, and in the sight of all the congregation of the children of Israel, who were weeping before the door of the tabernacle of the congregation. And when Phinehas, the son of Eleazar, the son of Aaron the priest, saw it, he rose up from among the congregation, and took a javelin in his hand; And he went after the man of Israel into the tent, and thrust both of them through, the man of Israel, and the woman through her belly. So the plague was stayed from the children of Israel. And those that died in the plague were twenty and four thousand.

It says that Israel yoked themselves to the BaalPeor. The Lord asks Moses to take all the chiefs of the people and hang them in the sun before the Lord.   Instead, Moses says to the judges of Israel to kill those of the men who have yoked themselves to the BaalPeor. Was he interpreting the command of the Lord properly, or was he making it an acceptable course of action, or was this what the God meant in the first place? And then, we are in the midst of a plague. Can anyone untangle this passage for me?

Answer (score 5):

This is a great question.

Numbers 25:4 (KJV)

> And the LORD said unto Moses, Take all the heads of the people, and hang them up before the LORD against the sun, that the fierce anger of the LORD may be turned away from Israel.

"the heads of the people" here in Hebrew **רָאשֵׁי** .הָעָם רָאשֵׁי *rashi* which means *main, major, captain, leader, chief* etc

So YHWH is saying to Moses per Moses' interpretation "take the *main* or *major offenders* of all the people".

So absolutely Moses' response was right in accord with YHWH's command.

Also it is not *Baal of Peor*, rather it's **לְבַעַל פְּער** Baal~Peor.

As for the plague, we'd deduce that this was an attribute of Numbers 25:3

> And Israel joined himself unto Baalpeor: and the anger of the LORD was kindled against Israel.

So the anger of YHWH was unfolding against Israel, part or all of this anger was in the form of a plague.

Psalms 106:30 (KJV)

> Then stood up Phinehas, and executed judgment: and so the plague was stayed.

---

*Hebrew words used are from the* Westminster Leningrad Codex.

Answer (score 3):

I believe​ the plague that killed 24,000 was a sexual disease. Let me explain.

In Numbers 31 we read that under God's direction, Moses sent the Israelites to Midian, they killed all the men but brought back all the children and women. When Moses saw the women and children that they brought back he became angry and says this:

> <sup>15</sup> “Have you allowed all the women to live?” he asked them. <sup>16</sup> “They were the ones who followed Balaam’s advice and enticed the Israelites to be unfaithful to the Lord in the Peor incident, so that a plague struck the Lord’s people. <sup>17</sup>Now kill all the boys. And kill every woman who has slept with a man, <sup>18</sup>but save for yourselves every girl who has never slept with a man <sup>19</sup>Anyone who has killed someone or touched someone who was killed must stay outside the camp seven days. On the third and seventh days you must purify yourselves and your captives. <sup>20</sup>Purify every garment as well as everything made of leather, goat hair or wood.
>   -- Numbers 31:15-20 (NIV)

Moses was angry and said, "*Have you allowed all the women to live ...*", because they were the ones who enticed the Israelites with sex and idolatry and brought upon yourselves a plague.

I believe the plague to be a sexual disease because the Israelites contracted the plague after fornicating with these women and Moses told them to kill all the women who had sex but let the virgins live, because they didn't have this sexual disease. Then he goes on to say whoever killed someone or touched someone that was killed must stay outside for 7 days and purify yourselves and the virgins. He even made them cleanse their clothes and burn their weapons because they would have had the blood of an infected man on everything. And then lastly, when Phinehas saw the Israelite man bring a Midian woman Kozbi into the camp and begins having sex with her, he stabs them both and kills them and then God said now the plaque has lifted. See, Kozbi was the one who started it all. God said:

> <sup>17</sup>Treat the Midianites as enemies and kill them. <sup>18</sup>They treated you as enemies when they deceived you in the Peor incident involving their sister Kozbi, the daughter of a Midianite leader.
>   -- Numbers 25:17-18 (NIV)

She started the plague by luring the Israelites with sex, and her death during sex ended the plague.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! Please [take the tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site functions. I have presented the same argument [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/28135/10955), but it didn't receive any positive responses. Nevertheless, +1 from me.

Comment: @Amy Given (Cozbi) Kozbi's seniority among the Midianites since she was a daughter of leader, she probably certainly had a key role in luring the Israelites to indulge in sexual sin, but I do Not know if she was the person who initiated any kind of sexual enticement

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

Moses’s command aligns with the command of the Lord and this incident has a message for the Lord’s people today.

“Baal”= “lord”.   “Peor” = “gap” or opening….. and in this context speaks of the cavity of the “stomach” or belly.

This all points to the cavity of the “belly” just as Phinehas shows us via the javelin through the belly :

> Numbers 25:7-8 KJV (7)  *And when Phinehas, the son of Eleazar, the son
>   of Aaron the priest, saw it, he rose up from among the congregation,
>   and took a javelin in his hand; (8)  And he went after the man of
>   Israel into the tent, and thrust both of them through, the man of
>   Israel, and the woman **through her belly.** So the plague was stayed from
>   the children of Israel.*

The enemies of the cross of Christ serve only for their “belly”…the stomach…the cavity…the “gap”….Peor.   Their “God is their belly” = Baalpeor.

As they “preach” for money, they are only minding earthly things:  what to eat, what to drink, what to wear.   Their end is destruction and those who sit together with them (the “fornication") are being destroyed along with them.

> Philippians 3:18-19 KJV (18)  *(For many walk, of whom I have told you
>   often, and now tell you even weeping, that they are the enemies of the
>   cross of Christ: (19)  **Whose end is destruction, whose God is their
>   belly,** and whose glory is in their shame, who mind earthly things.)*

We must not be joined with them in their “churches” where covetous people preach things that they ought not be in order to get money.   We must not bow down and do their teachings for money’s sake.  We must not eat with such...having no fellowship with.

> Numbers 25:1-3 KJV (1)  And Israel abode in Shittim, and the people
>   began to commit whoredom with the daughters of Moab. (2)  **And they
>   called the people unto the sacrifices of their gods: and the people
>   did eat, and bowed down to their gods.** (3)  **And Israel joined himself
>   unto Baalpeor: and the anger of the LORD was kindled against Israel.**

“Meats for the belly and the belly for meats”…but God shall destroy both it and them.  We must not be brought under the power of any who are preaching for their belly’s sake or we are destroyed along with them.

> 1 Corinthians 6:12-20 KJV (12)  *All things are lawful unto me, but all
>   things are not expedient: all things are lawful for me, but I will not
>   be brought under the power of any.*

Our mortal body is not for “fornication”…that is, it is not meant to be joined along with those who are preaching for money’s sake as they serve only for their own belly and not the Lord.

> (13)  **Meats for the belly, and the belly for meats: but God shall
>   destroy both it and them. Now the body is not for fornication,** but for
>   the Lord; and the Lord for the body. (14)  And God hath both raised up
>   the Lord, and will also raise up us by his own power.

We must not take our mortal bodies which are the members of Christ and make them members of a “harlot”….those who are preaching for money’s sake (serving for their own belly).  We must not be joined to “Baalpeor”...the fornication.

> (15)  ***Know ye not that your bodies are the members of Christ? shall I
>   then take the members of Christ, and make them the members of an
>   harlot?*** God forbid.

If we are joined along with them in their congregations, then we are one flesh with them….and are being destroyed along with them as our mortal bodies…our flesh…. perish in their destruction.  This is the “plague”.

> (16)  ***What? know ye not that he which is joined to an harlot is one
>   body? for two, saith he, shall be one flesh.*** (17)  But he that is
>   joined unto the Lord is one spirit.

We must not sit together with them (the  “fornication” we are to flee) affirming  of and doing their commandments…bowing down to them… in their churches.  If we do, then we are being destroyed along with them and sin against our own mortal body.

> (18)  **Flee fornication. Every sin that a man doeth is without the
>   body; but he that committeth fornication sinneth against his own body.**

Our mortal body is the temple of the Holy Spirit and we are bought with a price.  We are the Lord’s.   We must glory God in our mortal bodies by not sitting together with them as their end is destruction.  We must flee the “fornication” by coming out from among them.

> (19)  *What? know ye not that **your body is the temple of the Holy Ghost
>   which is in you,** which ye have of God, and ye are not your own? (20) 
>   For ye are bought with a price: **therefore glorify God in your body,
>   and in your spirit, which are God's**.*

This is the message we see in the historical example found in Numbers 25 that was written for us today.  It is showing us what to do today.

To “hang them up” is to be “severed” from those “heads”…those men who love to be first who are preaching for their own belly’s sake and are not serving the Lord.  We must sever ourselves from their company “against the sun”…that is, in broad daylight.   It is a judgment call that everyone shall see in the light of day as we leave their company and show that we love the Father.

> Numbers 25:4-5 KJV (4)  *And the LORD said unto Moses, **Take all the
>   heads of the people, and hang them up before the LORD against the sun**,
>   that the fierce anger of the LORD may be turned away from Israel.*

Our mortal body is our “man”.  We must slay everyone “his men”…the mortal body…that were joined unto them.

We must glorify God in our mortal body and terminate our companionship with those who are serving for their own belly.   Moses said this unto the “judges” of Israel as we judge them by leaving their company.  “Do you not judge them that are within”?

> (5)  **And Moses said unto the judges of Israel, Slay ye every one his
>   men that were joined unto Baalpeor.**

We must not keep company with those who call themselves “brothers” but are covetous and are worshipping “Baalpeor” as they serve their lord stomach...their “god is their belly”.

> 1 Corinthians 5:9-13 KJV (9)  ***I wrote unto you in an epistle not to
>   company with fornicators:*** (10)  Yet not altogether with the
>   fornicators of this world, or with the covetous, or extortioners, or
>   with idolaters; for then must ye needs go out of the world.

We must not keep company with the covetous….which such a one not to eat.

> (11)  **But now I have written unto you not to keep company, if any man
>   that is called a brother be a fornicator, or covetous, or an idolater,
>   or a railer, or a drunkard, or an extortioner; with such an one no not
>   to eat**.

“Do you not judge them that are within”?   The “judges” of Israel are to put away from themselves those who call themselves “brothers” but are covetous.  We must put from among us the wicked.  We must not be joined to them in their serving for the belly’s sake….their “Baalpeor”…or we face their judgment…their end…. along with them which is destruction of our mortal body…the destruction of the flesh.

> (12)  F*or what have I to do to judge them also that are without? **do
>   not ye judge them that are within?** (13)  But them that are without God
>   judgeth. **Therefore put away from among yourselves that wicked person***.

No covetous man, who is an idolater, has any inheritance in the kingdom of Christ and of God which is eternal.   They do not have eternal life.   We must not sit together with them where they are not serving the Lord but only for their own belly…the Baalpeor.

> Ephesians 5:5-7 KJV (5)  ***For this ye know, that no whoremonger, nor
>   unclean person, nor covetous man, who is an idolater, hath any
>   inheritance in the kingdom of Christ and of God***.

Their end is destruction of their mortal bodies from this earth as the wrath of God comes upon them…and also those who sit together with them (the “fornication”).

> (6)  *Let no man deceive you with vain words: for **because of these
>   things cometh the wrath of God upon the children of disobedience**.*

Be not partakers with them.  We must come out from among them and be separate.

> **(7)  Be not ye therefore partakers with them.**

They do not serve the Lord Jesus Christ but their own belly….their Baalpeor….their lord stomach.

> Romans 16:17-18 KJV (17)  *Now I beseech you, brethren, mark them which
>   cause divisions and offences contrary to the doctrine which ye have
>   learned; and avoid them. (18)  **For they that are such serve not our
>   Lord Jesus Christ, but their own belly;** and by good words and fair
>   speeches deceive the hearts of the simple.*

Our mortal body is the temple of the living God and we must not be joined with “Baalpeor” or we perish as God destroys the temple.   We must not defile our mortal body (the temple of God) by joining their churches.

> 1 Corinthians 3:16-17 KJV (16)  ***Know ye not that ye are the temple of
>   God, and that the Spirit of God dwelleth in you?*** (17)  **If any man
>   defile the temple of God, him shall God destroy;** for the temple of God
>   is holy, which temple ye are.

What agreement does the temple of God have with idols?  Covetousness is idolatry.

> 2 Corinthians 6:16-18 KJV (16)  ***And what agreement hath the temple of
>   God with idols? for ye are the temple of the living God;*** as God hath
>   said, I will dwell in them, and walk in them; and I will be their God,
>   and they shall be my people.

We must come out from among them and be separate.

> (17)  ***Wherefore come out from among them, and be ye separate, saith
>   the Lord, and touch not the unclean thing; and I will receive you***,
>   (18)  And will be a Father unto you, and ye shall be my sons and
>   daughters, saith the Lord Almighty.

We must cleanse ourselves from all filthiness of the flesh and spirit.

> 2 Corinthians 7:1 KJV (1)  *Having therefore these promises, dearly
>   beloved, **let us cleanse ourselves from all filthiness of the flesh and
>   spirit,** perfecting holiness in the fear of God.*

Those who sit together with the covetous preachers are given over to dishonoring their own mortal bodies between themselves.

We must flee their congregations  as we are one flesh with them in their destruction as they (the money changers) are exchanging the glory of God that is due Him from all nations into an image make like to corruptible man (money that has the image of man upon it).  They preach for money’s sake and the rest of the world blasphemes His holy name because of them rather than praise Him.

> Romans 1:22-24 KJV (22)  *Professing themselves to be wise, they became
>   fools, (23)  **And changed the glory of the uncorruptible God into an
>   image made like to corruptible man,** and to birds, and fourfooted
>   beasts, and creeping things. (24)  Wherefore God also gave them up to
>   uncleanness through the lusts of their own hearts, **to dishonour their
>   own bodies between themselves**:*

The “moneychangers” are exchanging the glory of God for money’s sake.  His house is to be called of all nations the house of prayer as they are to look to us and praise God above….but instead it has been made a “den of thieves” and the outside world sees this and does not give glory to God that is due Him.

> Mark 11:15-17 KJV (15)  *And they come to Jerusalem: and Jesus went
>   into the temple, and began to cast out them that sold and bought in
>   the temple, and overthrew the tables of **the moneychangers**, and the
>   seats of them that sold doves;*

No man is able to carry his “vessel”….the mortal body….through the temple as they are being destroyed.

> (16)  ***And would not suffer that any man should carry any vessel
>   through the temple.*** (17)  And he taught, saying unto them, Is it not
>   written, **My house shall be called of all nations** the house of prayer?
>   but ye have made it a den of thieves.

We must not eat with them…with those who exchanging the glory of God that is due Him….as they only serve for their earthly needs.  They preach things that they ought not for money’s sake as they go upon the belly after earthly things (earthly necessities).

> Leviticus 11:41-45 KJV (41)  *And every creeping thing that creepeth
>   upon the earth shall be an abomination; it shall not be eaten. (42) 
>   **Whatsoever goeth upon the belly, and whatsoever goeth upon all four,**
>   or whatsoever hath more feet among all creeping things that creep upon
>   the earth, **them ye shall not eat;** for they are an abomination.*

We must not eat with them or we make ourselves unclean with them.  We must not serve their commandments (such as “tithing”, etc) which are only preached in order to get money for earthly needs.

> (43)  *Ye shall not make yourselves abominable with any creeping thing
>   that creepeth, **neither shall ye make yourselves unclean with them,
>   that ye should be defiled thereby**.*

We must sanctify ourselves by not keeping company with those who only serve for their earthly needs….as they “creep upon the earth” after them.

> (44)  ***For I am the LORD your God: ye shall therefore sanctify
>   yourselves, and ye shall be holy;*** for I am holy: neither shall ye
>   defile yourselves with any manner of creeping thing that creepeth upon
>   the earth. (45)  For I am the LORD that bringeth you up out of the
>   land of Egypt, to be your God: ye shall therefore be holy, for I am
>   holy.

We must not sit together with the covetous (the “fornication”) and doing their covetous practices along with them..... for this is the will of God, our sanctification.

> 1 Thessalonians 4:2-4 KJV (2)  *For ye know what commandments we gave
>   you by the Lord Jesus. (3)  **For this is the will of God, even your
>   sanctification, that ye should abstain from fornication**:*

The “vessel” is the mortal body. We must not be joined together who are serving for their own belly and not the Lord.

> (4)  That every one of you should know how to possess his vessel in
>   sanctification and honour;

These covetous men ….who are the  “heads” of the churches….who are at the pinnacle of the temple….who are upon the “housetop”…use feigned words to make merchandise of us.

Their judgment of a long time does NOT linger and their destruction does not sleep.

They are collectively called the “son of perdition” as they are currently under His wrath and if we sit together with them we also perish along with them in their mortal destruction from off this earth.

The mystery of iniquity is ALREADY at work as those who sit together with the “son of perdition” are being mortally destroyed from off this earth.

> 2 Peter 2:3 KJV (3)  ***And through covetousness shall they with feigned
>   words make merchandise of you: whose judgment now of a long time
>   lingereth not, and their damnation slumbereth not***.

The false prophet (the “son of perdition”) is a destroyer as he deceives those who continue to sow after the flesh in their earthly wisdom (envy, strife, hatred, wrath, etc) and do deaden the deeds of the body through the Spirit.

The wrath of God is revealed from Heaven upon the children of disobedience as they are being destroyed from the earth as their destruction does not slumber.  All of those who go and sit together with the false prophet are also being destroyed.   The false prophet (who falsely prophesies “peace” in their congregations) is the son of perdition.  He makes fire come down from Heaven on the earth which destroys those who sit with him and even upon himself.  The desolator is destroyed also.

> Revelation 13:13 KJV (13)  **And he doeth great wonders, so that he
>   maketh fire come down from heaven on the earth in the sight of men,**

Their presence (“coming”) is in accordance with the working of Satan to deceive and destroy those who do not receive the love of the Truth so that they might be saved.  The son of destruction deceives those who take pleasure in unrighteousness.

> 2 Thessalonians 2:9-12 KJV (9)  *Even him, whose coming is after the
>   working of Satan with all power and signs and lying wonders, (10)  And
>   with all deceivableness of unrighteousness **in them that perish;**
>   because they received not the love of the truth, that they might be
>   saved. (11)  And for this cause God shall send them strong delusion,
>   that they should believe a lie: (12)  **That they all might be damned**
>   who believed not the truth, but had pleasure in unrighteousness.*

The “son of perdition” will be revealed among us.  But first we must come out from among them and be separate  so as not to be any longer joined together with them in their destruction. We must instead be gathered together in the Lord.